# Magento 2: DevTool access issue on browser

Tags: magento2

I am not able to access the Magento 2 dev tool in the chrome extension.
Anyone, please suggest to me where I am wrong.

**Following this url :** [Advanced Js Bundling](https://newbedev.com/magento-2-advanced-js-bundling)

Thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you correctly installed the extension in your Magento?

Comment: Yes, I have cloned the directory on my local machine

Comment: Is this site-specific access?

Comment: I have cloned M2-dev-tool outside Magento root project folder

Comment: Any reply @AlanZavagli

Comment: HI, Me too getting same issue. Got any solution for it?